# hydra target ssh does not support password authentication

Tags: macos, authentication, ssh, server, hydra

I am using Hydra v8.1 downloaded and compiled from a tar file. I've managed to solve the standard problem of libssh support and now when I try to make an attack(I think it's called dictionary attack) on an SSH server, after specifying the following command:

```
hydra -l {username} -s {port} -P /Users/{UserName}/Desktop/{file}.txt {ip} ssh
```

I get the following output:

```
Hydra v8.1 (c) 2014 by van Hauser/THC - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2015-09-30 10:59:49
[WARNING] Many SSH configurations limit the number of parallel tasks, it is recommended to reduce the tasks: use -t 4
[DATA] max 7 tasks per 1 server, overall 64 tasks, 7 login tries (l:1/p:7), ~0 tries per task
[DATA] attacking service ssh on port {port}
[ERROR] target ssh://{ip}:{port}/ does not support password authentication
```

I have enabled support for the required libraries and I am running an OS X environment.

Can someone indicate a solution to this problem? Thank you.

**Note**: If I manually log in with the username and password, the authentication grants access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

from another board:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183848/hydra-fails-with-error-target-ssh-192-168-16-12822-does-not-support-passw

SSH supports several different authentication mechanisms. The password authentication mechanism has the client send the password to the server as a password. The more-common keyboard-interactive authentication mechanism opens a channel between the client and an authentication process on the server. The client allows the user to directly interact with the authentication process, which is usually just a password prompt. This allows more complex features like multiple-factor authentication and pre-authentication warnings and checks.

So your target probably supports keyboard-interactive and not password authentication.